# Chaining methods in PHP and execute the first called method as last, how does it work?

Tags: php, laravel, method-chaining

I'm working with Laravel for a little while now and since the start I have been wondering how they are able to chain methods in a random order and still execute the whole chain as one operation.

For example, in the console kernel:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('some-command')
        ->everyThirtyMinutes()
        ->before(function (Schedule $schedule) {
            $schedule->command('some-other-command');
        });
}
```

The `command` method is called first, but the command will only run every thirty minutes. That information came after calling the `command` method, but is still processed before executing it. The same goes for the `before` method. That method is called last, but the `some-other-command` command is still being executed first.

I've searched the internet for the answer, but I couldn't find one. I hope you know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That method is called last, but the some-other-command command is still being executed first.

Because that is what the `before()` method does, placing another command before (hence the name) the current command. 
And as the class name `Scheduler` implies, it's setting up some schedule, not executing the code as is, so the question is rather a misunderstanding of what the code does.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I wasn't aware of the fact that the commands are being collected on a higher level and then run in the right order according to the instructions given. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context where you are using the chaining, in your example the first method is [command](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.html#method_command) :

> Add a new Artisan command event to the schedule.

And it returns an [Event](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html), this Event instance has a lot of methods that you can call in chaining mode because they return `$this` witch mean they return the current instance of the event, so that you can call an other method that the Event` class offers.

In your example

- [everyThirtyMinutes](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_everyThirtyMinutes)

> Schedule the event to run every thirty minutes.
>   Return Value : $this

- [before](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_before)

> Register a callback **to be called before the operation**.
>   Return Value : $this

Concerning the order you have to call `command` first to get the `Event` instance, and for the tow other methods the order has no effect.

Like if you told to someone go to the market every thirty minutes and before each time close the house door, it's the same thing if you told him (or her) before you go to the market close the house door and go every thirty minutes.